# SwiftUI: macOS toolbar is initially greyed out

Tags: macos, swiftui, toolbar

When I first launch my app the toolbar icons are shown and work fine, but they are initially greyed out until mousing over the button.

First run of the app:

[image]

and then mouse over:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View
{
    @State var mainList:[String] = ["Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Golf", "Hotel", "Indigo", "Juliet", "Kilo", "Lima", "Mike", "November", "Oscar", "Papa", "Quebec", "Romeo", "Sierra", "Tango", "Uniform", "Victor", "Whisky", "Xray", "Yankee", "Zulu"]
    @State var selectedItem:String? = "Echo"
    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationView
        {
            List()
            {
                ForEach(mainList, id: \.self)
                {item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item), tag: item, selection: $selectedItem, label:
                                    {
                                        Text("\(item)")
                                    })
                    
                }
            }
        }
        .toolbar
        {
            Button(action: {addNewItem()})
            {
                Label("Select", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func addNewItem()
    {
        print ("Add item")
    }
    
}

struct DetailView: View
{
    @State var item: String
    
    var body: some View
    {
        Text(item)
    }
}
```

This is in Xcode 12.5.1 and Xcode 13.0 beta.

I would have thought that the toolbar should be enabled at active with this code. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The bug seems to be in Button(). Here is a workaround that works for me. The only downside is that it lacks the visual feedback of the Button when pressed.

```
        .toolbar
        {
            Label("Select", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
                .onTapGesture(perform: {addNewItem()})
        }
```